# How to bypass fingerprint lock screen with wiping memory?

Tags: lock-screens

My fiancee has recently died and he had set his android note 4 to lock with his fingerprint. The family and I want to recover some of his photos and videos. How would I go about doing that without wiping the memory?

Answer (score 0):

There is no regular way to do so if you do not have a backup. However, you can try this, if you are comfortable with using recovery.

Flash the file from this XDA thread in recovery: http://forum.xda-developers.com/note-4/orig-development/bypass-lock-screen-pattern-password-pin-t2948336, which will reset lock screen back to Swipe.

Alternately, you can: (Not sure if this will work, just my idea)

1. Install TWRP recovery with Odin
2. Insert a SD Card of your choice
3. Boot into your newly-installed TWRP recovery
4. Mount SD Card, System and Data partitions
5. Default storage area is `/storage/emulated/0`
6. You can access the data using the built-in File Manager to copy the data out to your SD Card, which is located in `/sdcard`